# Batch: set a variable with a filename

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm stuck with my batch script. I'm in a folder in which I know that there is a single file with the .txt extension. I want to be able to stock the filename, with or without the extension in a variable(using set).

I don't know how to search for this file...

Thanks in advance :)

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the script is executed in the same directory as the file:

```
for %%# in (*.txt) do set "file_name=%%~nx#"
```

Comment: Thanks. It help ! I just change a little : for %%G in (*.p4d) do set "projName=%%G"

Answer (score 1):

Use dir to generate a list of *.txt files in a temporary file `dir /b *.txt > tmp`.  This will be just one file in your case.  Load that list into a variable `set /p VAR=<tmp`.  Tidy up by deleting the temporary file `del tmp`.  The file name you want is in variable VAR `echo %VAR%`